# Relocate all files to folder checkbox unavailable sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2012

Using SQL 2012 Enterprise edition

Following instructions here for restoring a backup:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186390.aspx#Restrictions

I need to be able to rename the database because it is the second copy on the instance (testing purposes). But I cannot rename it nor change the folders that it will restore the MDF/LDF files to.

For whatever reason the "Relocate all files to folder" checkbox is not available.

Restoring form a SQL 2005 backup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do this with T-SQL:

```
restore database YourDatabase_NewName
from disk = 'C:\YourDir\YourDatabase.bak'
with
    move 'YourDataFileName' to 'C:\DataDir\DataFile.mdf',
    move 'YourLogFileName' to 'C:\LogDir\LogFile.ldf'
go
```

Comment: +1 T-SQL is 1000 times better than the GUI. IMHO.

Comment: Yes! T-SQL Worked fine - I guess I'm submitting it as a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: Worked flawlessly - many thanks, have some upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

When you select the "Device" (file) to restore your database from, the Database combobox below is populated and the first item is selected.

But! Whatever event that populates the Files grid is not firing. If you explicitly select your database from that drop down, the Files grid will then populate and the "Relocate all files to folder" checkbox will enable.

Comment: thanks, selecting the "device" a second time properly refreshed the files page